# After enabling pretty URLs in yii2, how to give path to assets(images) in view files?

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

After enabling pretty urls path give for assets like images are failing to load. How to give path to static images in proper way in yii2?

Comment: "images are failing to load" - Are they not found, or different error? can you provide some code or how you define your URL? there's not enough data in this question to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example if you have upload your image in web/images/uploads folder
then you can access it using yii\helpers\Url, etc:

```
<img src="<?= Url::base(true)."/images/uploads/".$image_filename; ?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David. That worked! Cheers.

Comment: you're welcome. glad it worked